# Microsoft Azure Spot Instance Shutdown Script

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine

I'm training a Neural Network on an Azure Spot Instance VM and I want to be able to run a shutdown script that saves my model when the spot instance is evicted. Google Cloud has an option for a shutdown script. However, I haven't found an equivalent feature in Microsoft Azure. Essentially, I need to be able to send a SIGKILL signal to my program when my instance is being evicted. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: Not a `deep-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can think of is Azure Instance Metadata service which can be used for your scenario.

Instance Metadata service essentially provides an endpoint which you should invoke from *inside* your spot instance frequently. You can get the below events from the endpoint.

- Freeze
- Reboot
- Redeploy
- Terminate
- Preempt (*you are interested in this*)

Thus, the endpoint will let you know when the VM is going to be evicted. as per the links below, it gives a 30 seconds headsup wherein you may be able to do you clean up activities.

You can find more details here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service]

A good article on how to use the IMS can be found [here](https://dev.to/omiossec/working-with-azure-vm-spot-instance-1k02#:%7E:text=Azure%20Spot%20instance%20is%20a,not%20fixed%20like%20standard%20instances).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python script that monitors Azure VM eviction.

The script polls for the `http://169.254.169.254/metadata/scheduledevents` endpoint provided by the Azure host. `169.254.169.254` is a non-routable address provided by the host.

It can run any command before the VM is evicted, such as saving your work or stopping a service that does the save before being stopped. See the `def stop_service()` function - it contains the action.

You can run this Python script itself as a service.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# monitor-eviction.py

import json
from os import system, uname
from platform import node
from time import sleep

from requests import get

serviceToStop = "fishtest"
metadataUrl = "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/scheduledevents"
headerValur = {"Metadata": "true"}
queryParams = {"api-version": "2020-07-01"}
stopStatuses = ["Scheduled", "Started"]
stopTypes = ["Reboot", "Redeploy", "Freeze", "Preempt", "Terminate"]


def get_scheduled_events():
    resp = get(metadataUrl, headers=headerValur, params=queryParams)
    data = resp.json()
    return data


def stop_service():
    print("Stopping the service", serviceToStop, "...")
    rc = system("/usr/sbin/service " + serviceToStop + " stop")
    if rc == 0:
        print("Stopped.")
    else:
        print("Error! Return code", rc)


continueLoop = True

s = uname().release
if "azure" in s:
    myComputer = node()
    while continueLoop:
        payload = get_scheduled_events()
        if "Events" in payload.keys():
            print("Received payload", payload)
            for event in payload["Events"]:
                eventStatus = None
                if "EventStatus" in event.keys():
                    eventStatus = event["EventStatus"]
                eventType = None
                if "EventType" in event.keys():
                    eventType = event["EventType"]
                resourceType = None
                if "ResourceType" in event.keys():
                    resourceType = event["ResourceType"]
                resources = None
                if "Resources" in event.keys():
                    resources = event["Resources"]
                if (
                    (eventStatus in stopStatuses)
                    & (eventType in stopTypes)
                    & (resourceType == "VirtualMachine")
                    & (myComputer in resources)
                ):
                    print("Handling signal", eventType)
                    stop_service()
                    continueLoop = False
                    break
        if not continueLoop:
            break
        sleep(1)
else:
    print(s, "is not Azure!")
```